# How to display the result of where clause next App.app_num

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get all the applications which was updated before 5 business day

I am able to to get all the applications by using the following where clause calculation.

Also, I would like to display the number of day it was last updated.

```
SELECT A.APP_NUM
FROM Application A,

WHERE 
((Dayofyear(CURRENT_DATE) - Dayofyear(cast (A.LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP as DATE))) + 1) -     
((Week(CURRENT_DATE) - Week(cast (LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP as DATE))) * 2) - (case when     
DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) > 6 then 1 else 0 end) - (case when DAYOFWEEK(cast 
(LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP as DATE)) < 2 then 1 else 0 end) >
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [**DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

> expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one date to the other.
>   expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date
>   parts of the values are used in the calculation.

```
SELECT A.APP_NUM 
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), CAST(LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)) `no_of_days`
FROM Application A
WHERE .....
```